# Java RegEx Match; underscore before first decimal point

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, scripting, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a Java regex that will match an "_" before the instance of the first decimal point "."  Below doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
_(?=[0-9][0-9]\.)
```

Anyone have an idea on how I can accomplish this?  Example would be:

FileName:

```
Hello_World_5_01.00.0000
```

I would like to match the "_" between the characters "5_01."....Keep in mind that the above is an example filename and will vary, but the one constant will be the "_" before the instance of the first "." (decimal point) regardless of the filename itself.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want for java or javaScript ? please be clear with your tags

Comment: What do you want to extract? Can you add a [mre] to your question?

Comment: I am looking for a javaregex for a Javascript, I am not exactly attempting to extract anything other than a pattern match for the underscore  which occurs right before the first decimal point in a file name.  My above example shows I would like to match the "_" between the "5_01." within the filename "Hello_World_5_01.00.0000"

Answer (score 0):

You could match until the first occurrence of an underscore and capture that in a group.

Then match the following 1+ digits, a dot and if there has to be a digit following you can match that as well.

```
^.*?(_)\d+\.\d
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AmVmdr/1)

```js
const regex = /^.*?(_)\d+\.\d/;
const str = `Hello_World_5_01.00.0000`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```